# Blender preview render is different from final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

this is my first question here, I'm really new on Blender. I'm doing a tutorial that is very good, i make a donout. In the Preview Render window displays as:

[image]

But when I press F12 the result is so different:

[image]

Note the mug it seems doesn't have smooth and the donout is without the top part. I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the viewport with the same modifier settings for render and view? Modifiers like subdivision surface are not (by default) fully applied in view to save on computation time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm really new on Blender. Can you please guide me to check this things? Thanks

Comment: In the first photo posted in your question you can see the modifier stack in the sidebar. You have subdivision surface set to 1 in view and 2 in render. You can check if this causes the disparity by setting them both to 1 or 2. I would check the modifier stacks of the icing and doughnut.

Comment: I found it! The camera button on the modifier are off! Thanks a lot! Please write your answer to give to you the solution! Thanks!