# Holes in my final render that don't show in my preview

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, rendering

First Image is Shift-z. second is when I click render. This holes only show up in the final. It's like it's not registering part of the off set.[image]

Comment: Try to unhide all objects in the scene (Alt+H in 2.79) and see if any object is hidden in viewport but is shown in render

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117049/blender-preview-render-is-different-from-final-render

Answer (score 4):

I can bet, you use different subdiv levels for your preview, and render. If you make it equal, you will see the trouble in the viewport too.